# Making a search function in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a search function on my web page but it is not working. Can someone please tell me what is the problem of this code?

```
public function webSearch(Request $request)
{
    $articles = Article::where('title', '>', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
        ->orWhere('member', '>', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
        ->orWhere('excerpt', '>', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
        ->orWhere('body', '>', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->get();
    
    return view('pages/search');
}
```

**Search.blade.php**

```
@if($articles->isNotEmpty())
    @foreach ($articles as $article)
        <div class="article-list">
            <p>{{ $article->title }}</p>
            <img src="{{ $article->image }}">
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else 
    <div>
        <h2>No posts found</h2>
    </div>
@endif
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%news one%
> `title` > ? `member` > ? or `excerpt` > ? or `body` > ?' at line 1
> (SQL: select * from `articles` where %news one% `title` > LIKE
> `member` > LIKE or `excerpt` > LIKE or `body` > LIKE)

Answer (score 0):

There should be no > in your query.

change

```
$articles = Article::where('title', '>', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
```

with

```
$articles = Article::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
```

Comment: thnx a lot now i'm not having error but its getting me to empty url /search?search=news